# Capturing and processing data as soon as it is entered

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core

Looking for your suggestion on a good way to handle the below.

Need a fast input form for a receive scan webform app.  This will be collecting barcodes scanned off of packages one right after another.

the scans will be coming in from a bluetooth scanner into a input field.
after the scan the scanner will insert a CR.

At that point I just want to capture the data and pass it onto a controller for processing, clear the field and return control immediately back to the webpage for the next scan.

The biggest two problems are:

1. Speed – it has to be fast as they are doing real time scanning.
2. Keeping the input field the focus all the time so that when they
   scan they are not in some other field on the screen.  They will start off in the input field, I just need to make sure they go right back to it after each scan automatically.

Any thoughts on how you would best handle?

Here is my HTML:

```
<input type="text" 
   id="barcode" 
   name="barcode" 
   value="" 
   onchange="location.href='@Url.Action("scanned", "receiveScan")?barcode=' + $('#barcode').val()"><br>
```

And this is the controller action:

```
 public ActionResult scanned(string barcode)
    {
        //code to process goes here
        return Ok();
    }
```

Afterwards it resets the webpage to a blank page.

Instead what I need to do is just blank the input field and put the focus back to it.

I do have it working by modifying the controller to be:

```
   public ActionResult scanned(string barcode)
{
    var test = barcode;
    //code to process goes here
  return  RedirectToAction("receiveScan", "home");

}
```

But it has been pointed out that reposting the entire page is not a good idea.
I will try one of the solutions below as soon as I can get back to it.

Thanks for the help, here is the code that worked --

```
 $('#textArea1').val('Scans - ');
$(function () {
    $("#barcode").on("change", function (e) {
        // get the current value
        var barcode = $('#barcode').val();

        // if there's no text, ignore the event
        if (!barcode) {
            return;
        }
       // clear the textbox
        $("#barcode").val("");

       // var holdit = $('#textArea1').val();
        $('#textArea1').val($('#textArea1').val() +' '+ barcode);
         // post the data using AJAX
    $.post('@Url.Action("scanned", "receiveScan")?barcode=' + barcode);
    });
})
```

Comment: As I understand your question, you need help with the client-side part of the application, not the server-side. Nothing on the c# side can help you with this

Comment: Correct...I have a solid handle on how to process each scan once the data is collected.  My problem is I am a winforms programmer muddling around in a webapp.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto -- I agree it is broad.  I don't know if I agree that it is too broad.  Looking for about 3 lines of code from somebody to point me the right direction, not a complete solution.  Your comment is helpful actually.

Comment: I don't see why 1. and 2. are issues! Your UI should just make background calls to your webservice each time a new code is received. Doing it in the background should keep the focus on your input all the time and there's no speed issue because you'll be sending requestes as soon as new data arrives. You can even do it in batches.

Comment: I think the issue I am having is I don't want the whole page to post.

Comment: Your right, doing background calls to a webservice vs directly updated the database from the controller will be better as well.  I will update the question later on when I get further into this.

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect the code I am using.  Like I said, I think I need to stop the page from posting upon return?

Comment: I think you should consider using an AJAX call in in the back ground to handle this. You also could just put a multi line input box on the screen and let them scan it all and then submit it one time at the end.

Comment: I need the scans to process as they are entered.  I will google how to do a AJAX call now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of performing a full postback, you should be using an AJAX call to ensure that the page is not completely reloaded.

Here's an example of how you could do this (untested, might have typos):

```
<input type="text" id="barcode" name="barcode"/>

$(function() 
{
    $("#barcode").on("change", function (e)
    {
        // get the current value
        var barcode = $('#barcode').val();

        // if there's no text, ignore the event
        if (!barcode)
        {
            return;
        }

        // clear the textbox
        $("#barcode").val("");

        // post the data using AJAX
        $.post('@Url.Action("scanned", "receiveScan")?barcode=' + barcode);
});
```

Note that this assumes that the device will actually paste the entire data at once. If you find that the event is firing too often, you will need to implement some throttling around the `change` event.

Comment: I like that...I will test it out.  Thank you for the time to enter it.